# Make a list from search result elements than submit it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, list, search

There's a search field in my index which is search in a mysql db.
The result have link with a product ID, so it's clickable.

I want to make a list from the search result elements which i clicked and take it in a form.
So when i have the list i want to submit all of those to another page.

I think the best idea for that is javascript's click event. 
Found some js code on the internet, but i can't use it well, because unfortunately i don't have enough knowledge for javascript yet.

What is the simpliest solution?

*javascript what i found*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            $("ul").append("<li>product name! <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'>×</a></li>"); 
        });
        $(document).on("click", "a.remove" , function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

*search.php*

```
<?php

include './config/functions.php';
dbconn();

$html = '';
$html .= '<div class="result">';
$html .= '<a href="urlString" name="urlString">';
$html .= '<h3>category: <b>nameString</b></h3>';
$html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</div>';


$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);

if (strlen($search_string) >= 2 && $search_string !== '') {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE pro_name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

            $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['pro_name']);
            $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['pro_category']);
            $display_url = "index.php?".urlencode($_GET['mode'])."&send=".urlencode($result['pro_id']);

            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);
            $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);
            $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);

            echo($output);
        }
    }else{

        $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No result to show!</b>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

        echo($output);
    }
}
?>
```

*search function in index.php*

```
function product_search(){
  $html = '<div id="main">
   <div class="icon"></div>
    <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
    <h4 id="results-text">search key: <b id="search-string"></b></h4>
    <ul id="results"></ul>
  </div>';
  echo $html;
}
```